# How to bond polymer to polymer (TPU on PMMA)

Tags: bond, polymers, surface-chemistry

**TL;DR** I wanted to bond TPU films to PMMA slab. I  have tried thermal bonding but it is was not practical (I do not know why?). Can anyone please give me a method to bound them?

"Thermal bonding" means we melted the surface and tried sticking them together. We want to bond TPU (thermoplastic polyurethane) to PMMA, for microfluidic projects, with in submilimitere features on PMMA slab and a very thin film of TPU (50 micron). We want to decrease the time and temperature if it is thermal bonding because the temperature used in references is more than 105°C which maybe deform micro patterns on PMMA slab. We also appreciate other ways you may propose.

Comment: "Thermal bonding" means you melted the surface and tried sticking them together?

Comment: Yes @Karl and I want to the ways to improve it

Comment: That´s tbe. Most polymers do not mix. Judging from your comment below, your are trying to do a scientific project. What did your literature research yield? You are certainly not the first to try this!

Comment: @Karl, we found researchers typically use it in the pressures much lower than our desired amount. We want to work in higher pressures. In most researches, people use thermal bonding with some chemical treatment but it is very tedious, time consuming and against rapid production. Please let me know if there's need any more information that I can provide for you.

Comment: related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32060/102629

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say but you question is a bit vague because without knowing the project, it's pretty hard to help. Anyway, here is some general information.
Some of the sophisticated methods of joining these together include solvent bonding, vibration welding, friction welding and induction welding or pressure sensitive adhesives [ (Meth)acrylic copolymers are one of the most widely used polymer classes for the production of pressure-sensitive adhesives]. Acrylic requires an acrylic solvent adhesive. Cyanoacrylate (super glue) may work, depending on the project. UHU glue is very useful with all kinds of plastics, so you might wanna try that.  I myself have tried superglue and it works with both materials. But I think for your project, non adhesive methods woll be an optimal choice.
All the best.

Comment: Thanks for your help
We want to bond TPU (thermoplasticl polyurethane) to PMMA, for microfluidic projects, with in submilimitere features on PMMA slab and a very thin film of TPU (50micron). We want to decrease the time and temperature if it is thermal bonding because the temperature used in references is more than 105 which maybe deform micro patterns on PMMA slab, we also appreciate other ways if you propose.

Comment: Hello, as I have already given you a brief account of other options, I won't repeat them. But here is a paper that might help you. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1333pQJA7eiVa-sE__7ZYGK2vBy4w4bnP/view?usp=drivesdk